# Inequality Condition Bound

Tags: inequality

Let $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ be all real positive numbers and $b\leq c$ and $d \geq e$. Under what condition is $\frac{b}{d} \leq \frac{c}{e}$ ? I just need to come up with such a condition but for some reason, I am not quite arriving at a desirable condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$b\leq c$$ and $$e\le d$$
Multiply to get $$be\le cd$$

divide by $ed$ to get $$\frac{b}{d} \leq \frac{c}{e}$$
Since $b,c,d,e$ are positive the above actions are justified

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for something that satisfies the condition stated, not another representation of the condition needed.

Comment: sine your numbers are positive , with the given inequalities $b\leq c$ and $ e\leq d$

you do not need any extra conditions to have$ \frac{b}{d} \leq \frac{c}{e}$